# How to add a cdn in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

As I'm a beginner to Codeigniter, I don't know how to add cdn with  Codeigniter. If I add a cdn in normal method it doesn't load, but if I download the file and setup it locally it works. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: something like this; `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`, add it to the last of your views: remember 1st Php last: Javacript

Answer (score 2):

first you need CDN is a Content Delivery Network that just a content distribution by creator using their proxy servers or data center.

What you need to do for Add a CDN is just put in your header views file between `<head>` and `</head>`.

Example : `views/index.php`

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

That is a CDN file. Make sure the link and where you put it is correct, CDN will never result wrong in CodeIgniter.